# No color in Vim while using Google Cloud Shell

Tags: google-cloud

I have recently just got started using Google Cloud Machine Learning. I want to use Vim as my editor and it's there alright but after installing my `.vimrc` which enables syntax highlighting I'm stuck with black and white for some reason. I have color fine elsewhere. How can this issue be fixed?

Comment: The question was migrated from [su] to [webapps.se] but I think that it is unclear. Are you using a web application as it's defined on [help/on-topic]. Please add more details including a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested on [ask].

Comment: I am using Google Cloud Shell, as stated before. Certainly this is a web application. I am not sure what else is needed.

Comment: I think you should ask this question on https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Apparently thius questions was cross-posted to [vi.se] -> https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/18219/32792. I’m voting to close this question because cross-posting is not allowed across [se] sites.